# Insert Statement Based on Select Statement with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to create a static "copy" of values from one table and store them in another.

The best way I know how to do this is to get the values from the db to my application, loop through them and concatenate multiple `INSERT` statements, then execute the query.

Is there a way to do this without the round trip between application and database?

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentProject 
VALUES (SELECT StudentID, ProjectID 
        FROM dbo.StudentProjectSimulation
        WHERE SimulationID = 1)
```

but it doesn't.

(everything is an `int` so no worries there)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentProject 
SELECT StudentID, ProjectID 
FROM dbo.StudentProjectSimulation
WHERE SimulationID = 1
```

Comment: It is is poor practice to ever do an insert without defining the columns you want the insert to affect. If the table changes your code breaks. @BZN_DBer has the answer that should have been accepted.

Comment: I agree, but I was simply making as few changes to the OP's query as was needed to answer his question.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop `values` from the `insert into` clause.

```
Insert Into dbo.StudentProject 
Select StudentID, ProjectID  
From dbo.StudentProjectSimulation 
Where SimulationID = 1;
```

Comment: i liked your formatting better, though not much different than the others.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to explicitly define the columns to insert into use the following where you substitute `Student_Col` and `ProjectID_Col` for appropriate column names in `dbo.StudentProject`

```
Insert Into dbo.StudentProject 
  (
    Student_Col,
    ProjectID_Col
  )
Select 
  StudentID, 
  ProjectID 
From dbo.StudentProjectSimulation 
Where SimulationID = 1
```